# Submit primefaces table after select

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, datatable, form-submit

I have a table in Primefaces with a single selection. After the user selects an entry of that table, the whole form should be submitted. I could use a commandbutton to sumbit, but I don't want the user to do this, cause the selection is the last and final step of the form.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.selectedItems}" var="selItem"
                         selection="#{bean.selectedItem}" 
                         rowKey="#{selItem.id}"
                         selectionMode="single"
                         id="selectedTbl">
                 <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{bean.onSelectListener}"/>
                 <p:column selectionMode="single"/>
                 ...
<p:dataTable/>
```

The ajax listener as well as the set method of the selectedItem is called, but how do I trigger a submit from ajax?

---

Update: More detailed example

Case: Only one person per group can be enabled. The user has to decide based on many information in a table. And sometimes the user has to do this very often.

```
<h:form>
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.group}" valueChangeListener="#{bean.onGroupChange}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select..." noSelectionOption="true"/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{bean.groups}"/>
                <p:ajax update="selectedTbl"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:dataTable value="#{bean.selectedItems}" var="selItem"
                         selection="#{bean.selectedItem}" 
                         rowKey="#{selItem.id}"
                         selectionMode="single"
                         id="selectedTbl">
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{bean.onSelectListener}"/>
                <p:column selectionMode="single"/>
                <p:column headerText="ID">
                    <h:outputText value="selItem.id"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Name">
                    <h:outputText value="selItem.name"/>
                </p:column>
                <!--Some more Information about the person, based on the the user makes a decision.--> 
                <p:dataTable/>

                <!--only one User per Group can be enabled-->
                <p:commandButton value="Enable" action="#{bean.enableSelected}" onclick="submit()"/>
        </h:form>
```

bean:

```
public void enableSelected(){
  manager.modifyPerson(selectItem);
  selectedItems.clear();
  selectedItem = null;
  group = null;
}
public void onSelectListener(SelectEvent event){
 selectedItem = (Person) event.getObject();
}
```

The bean is pretty simple only getter and setter. The onGroupChange Method loads new values for selectItems from the db.

I want to get rid of the commandbutton and move the functionality from enableSelected to onSelectListener. When I move the db-Function to enableSelected it works but the page isn't refreshed.

When I add update="@form" to ajax it doesn't work so I wanted to use submit().

Comment: What will happen when you submit the form ?!? do you persist or something like that ?!?

Comment: after the submit, everything in the form should be saved and the form should be resetted, so the user can can input another one

Comment: Just refresh the table by clearing the list ?!? and don't forget to udpate all the form

Comment: [mcve] please. For me it is not all that clear what you want to update/clear/submit...

Answer (score 0):

Try to add process="@form" in your ajax.

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" process="@form" listener="#{bean.onSelectListener}"/>
```